# Angularjs server side side redirection

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Need help about how to redirect to another domain from server side in angularjs application. I'm using spring MVC at my server side and angularjs at the frontend. 
I need to redirect to linkedin login url, But I cant able to redirect.Please help.

I'm using $http from angularjs to call springMVC controller. Also need a good explaination on which is the best way to redirect to other social media channels

```
LinkedInRequestToken requestToken = linkedInOAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(LINKEDIN_REDIRECTURL);
    String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthorizationUrl();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);
    try {
        response.sendRedirect(authUrl);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: If your handler method in the controller returns a string, you can return the string `"redirect:XXX"` (XXX would be the URL you are redirecting to) and spring will handle the rest.

Comment: @CodeChimp: Thank u so much for your reply. I tried out the "redirect:xxx" and with the help of firebug I also found the browser tries to redirect to XXXX url with code 302. but still there is no change in the URL or browser directs me to XXXXX

Comment: From the w3c site on HTTP response codes: "If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued."  I take that to mean that a 302 only works on GET and HEAD requests.  I am guessing yours is neither?  Source:  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html